# adding items to list box using jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I am a beginner to Servlets and Java I would like some help in adding items from a servlet to a list box. I have tired finding but not being successful.I want to add multiple items to the list box.

```
  this my servlet section

 String[] myStringArray = {"Motorola Solutions TC55","k35"};
      response.setIntHeader("default", 5);
        request.setAttribute("name",":Motorola Solutions TC55");
        request.setAttribute("item","myStringArray");

        request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/default.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

this is myjsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Include Manufacture name</title>
</head>
<body  >
<p id ="L1">Name :- <%=request.getAttribute("name")%></p>
<select>
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
    <option value='${item}'>${item}</option>
</c:forEach>

</select>
<button type="button" >Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to add the values in the array to the list box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use smth like

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

....

<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
    <option value='${item}'>${item}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

${items} array contains list of options.

If they have different id and title fields, it will look like

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
    <option value='${item.id}'>${item.title}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: So in my servlet id hav to set the attribute of item to wat i want it to display?

Comment: yes, for example see here - http://www.java2s.com/Questions_And_Answers/JSP-Servlet/JSTL/attribute.htm

Comment: sorry, don't understood you. Do you have taglib declared on page top?